# Unlink/File_exists diz que o arquivo não existe, mas o arquivo existe

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou com um problema com PHP, eu preciso de um script que exclua um arquivo num diretório, tudo passado por URL, como no script que eu fiz abaixo:

```
<?php

$file = !isset($_GET["f"])?0:$_GET["f"];
$dir = !isset($_GET["dir"])?"":$_GET["dir"];

var_dump($dir.$file);

if ($file === 0)
{
    echo 0;
    die();
}

if (file_exists($dir.$file)) 
    echo unlink($dir.$file);
else 
    echo 0;
```

?>

O problema está no seguinte, a função `file_exists()` e `unlink()`, das quais eu passo o caminho por parâmetro, dizem que o arquivo que estou tentando acessar não existe. Usando `var_dump()` percebi que o retorno é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> string(30) "C:\xampp\htdocs\aaaa\teste.txt"

O arquivo existe no diretório especificado, porém as funções dizem que não. Veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo existe, o diretório está correto, já tentei até com \\ (usar o desvio de caractere) mas da na mesma. Por favor, me ajudem!

Adendo de tentativas já feitas:

- Trocar file_exists() por is_file()
- Utilizar clearstatcache() antes de verificar o arquivo
- Trocar \ para \\

Nenhuma deu resultados, todas falharam.

Comment: No caso, a saída é `0`, devido ao `echo 0` no `else`? Já tentou indicar apenas o caminho relativo do arquivo?

Comment: Sim, a saída 0 é devido o echo 0, e o caminho relativo tentei agora mesmo, não resultou também. E estou usando o PHP 7 também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar, eu estava fazendo testes no meu computador local, algum tipo de bloqueio ou permissão (não pude identificar ainda) estava impedindo que a função is_file() ou file_exists() verificasse o arquivo.

Movi os arquivos para o servidor de produção da empresa, e agora funcionou, muito obrigado a todos.

Fiquei confuso, pois as pastas estavam com permissão de acesso total (do meu computador local), mas a solução para mim, foi testar no servidor de produção.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema esses dias atrás.

Tente utilizar **urldecode()** ao ler os parâmetros de GET:

```
$file = !isset($_GET["f"])?0:urldecode($_GET["f"]);
$dir = !isset($_GET["dir"])?"":urldecode($_GET["dir"]);
```

Pode ser que as barras estejam sendo convertidas para %2F

Comment: Não funcionou não, amigo :/

Comment: @JoãoRegis O que aparece no `var_dump()` de `$dir.$file` colocando o `url_decode()`?

Comment: O mesmo retorno anterior, "string(30) "C:\xampp\htdocs\aaaa\teste.txt" "

Comment: Tente trocar \ por /